# How to get first element of array returned by Angular resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I got response from server with $resource. In console it shows like:

```
$promise: Object,
$resolved: true,
0: f
```

How can I get that 0 element? When I try array[0] syntax I get *undefined*.

Here is my $resouce code:

```
angular.module('groupsModel', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Groups', function($resource) {
        var Groups = $resource('http://localhost:7777/api/users/:id/bands', {id:'@id'}, {'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true, params: {id:'@id'}}});

        return Groups;
    });
```

Comment: How are you accessing the array? Can you show that code?

Comment: Show us your Groups object

Comment: Where did you try the array[0] syntax ?

Comment: I'm trying to access array in controller. Here is code: var groups = Groups.query({id:$routeParams.id}); var group = groups[0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get resource you can do this

```
groupsModel.query()
```

because you named your first resource 'query'

and to get promise of this resource you can do

```
groupsModel.query().$promise
```

and to use data returned from the resource you can do

```
groupsModel.query().$promise.then(function(data){
// success, use data
}, function(err){
// failure, use err for logging etc...
});
```